# How to use Power Cards in Cluedo (David Walliams) Awful Auntie edition?

Tags: cluedo

My kids were given this game as a Christmas present this year. I played Cluedo for years as a kid myself, but it did not include the Power Cards feature of this edition. The instructions have the following to say on these cards:

> **Power Cards**
>
> You will see that some spaces on the board have question marks on
> them. If you land on a question mark you must take a Power Card from
> the pile and read it out. There are seven Kinds of Power Cards, and
> some will help you but some will hinder you. You must use the card on
> the turn you collect it, unless it specifies otherwise.

That all seems fine until you actually read some of the cards. Example card:

> **Dessert Distractions**
>
> A towering pyramid of chocolate balls distracts you. You cannot make any suggestions this turn.

Given that you can only make suggestions while in a room, and the fact that all question marks on the board are on squares between rooms, if you must land on a question mark to take a Power Card, how could you make a suggestion on 'this turn' anyway (since you are not in a room)?

To try to make sense of it, we re-interpreted the phrase 'If you land on a question mark' to 'If you pass over a question mark'. The kids decided this was a great opportunity to pass as many power cards as possible, rather than make their way to actual rooms though, and sometimes they ended up with 3 power cards in a single turn! It got ridiculous.

Ultimately, I think we will have to augment the rules to limit players to one Power Card per turn, but if somebody knows the true intent behind the use of these cards, I would love to hear it!

Comment: Sound like you have it right: the card has no material effect and exists only due to a lack of care/playtesting.

Answer (score 1):

This quote from the Power Card instructions:

> You must use the card on the turn you collect it

might be open to an alternate interpretation.

Initially (same as you) I would read it as "the card affects you on this turn", but maybe instead it means:

> You must **play the card, targeting yourself or another player** on the turn you collect it.

In the case of the Dessert Distractions Power Card, this means you could play the card against someone else, preventing them from making a suggestion on their next turn.

I'd be curious to know if the other cards worked well with this theory or not. *Some will help you but some will hinder you* suggests that the cards always target you, and the grammar of the quoted Power Card ('this turn') still seems clunky if it applies to another player's later turn.